# Do I need to report contributions to a Solo Roth 401(K) plan every year?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-401k, solo-401k

I am self employed. I recently shutdown my individual 401(K) plan at E*Trade. There was also a Roth 401(K) plan also. I am not sure if it is one plan or two.

I have been told by somebody at E*Trade that I should be reporting my contributions to the Roth 401(K) plan. He believes the correct form to use is form 5498 but he is not sure about the number. From what I see, that form is for IRA contributions not 401(K) contributions. Should I have been reporting my contributions to the Roth 401(K) each year and if so, how?

Note: I understand about form 5500ez and that I do not have to file it most years. I do have to file it this year because I am shutting down the plan.

I use Turbo Tax to do my income tax every year.

Comment: Is the total amount in the Solo 401(k) more than, or less than, $250,000?

Comment: It is less than $250,000.